# Ordenar un array de forma descendente en PHP

Tags: php, array

Necesito mostrar eso por pantalla con un `array` con PHP, alguna sugerencia?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
$number= array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
arsort($number);
for($x = 0; $x < count($number); $x++) {
    echo $number[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Mi primera sugerencia seria que revisese [ask]. Luego de eso, podrias mostrarnos algo de lo que hayas intentado? algo que tengas? de donde salen los datos? como estas mostrando actualmente?

Comment: 10 segundos buscando en [Google](http://php.net/manual/es/array.sorting.php) Recomiendo encaricidamente que visites [ask] y así puedas mejorar tu pregunta, añadiendo lo que has intentado hasta ahora y los errores que te han salido

Comment: Utiliza  [rsort($number);](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rsort.php) en lugar de `arsort`

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la función que buscas se llama `rsort` que orderna los valores en sentido descendente, `arsort` ordena y mantiene los índices asignados

```
$a=array(1,2,3,4);
rsort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Para tu caso podrías hacer

```
$number= array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
rsort($number);
for($x = 0; $x < count($number); $x++) {
    echo ($x+1) ."°-".$number[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, la función que mejor haría lo que quieres sería `rsort`.

Según [el Manual de PHP esta función](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rsort.php):

- Ordena un array en orden inverso (mayor a menor)

Y hay otra cosa interesante que dice:

- Esta función **asigna nuevas claves** a los elemenos del array.

Visto esto, una vez ordenado el array de mayor a menor, puedes trabajar **solamente con el array** para presentar los datos también. Dado que la función asigna nuevas claves, puedes leer en un `foreach` cada clave/valor del array para presentar el valor y el orden en que ha quedado. Dado que las claves empiezan por `0`, tendrías que sumar `1` a la clave en cada paso del bucle.

De este modo el código queda más limpio, y usas menos variables. Trabajarás únicamente con tu dato, por lo que ganarás en rendimiento.

Veamos:

#### ▸ Código:

**<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/BYA97550)</kbd>**

```
$arrNumbers= array("1","2","9","4","8","10","7","5","3","6");
rsort($arrNumbers);

foreach ($arrNumbers as $k=>$v){
    print ($k+1)."°- ".$v.PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### ▸ Resultado:

```
1°- 10
2°- 9
3°- 8
4°- 7
5°- 6
6°- 5
7°- 4
8°- 3
9°- 2
10°- 1
```

---

#### Nota adicional:

Dado que al parecer necesitarás hacer esta operación varias veces, puedes crear una función que haga el trabajo con sólo pasarle en parámetro el array.

La función sería más o menos así (la presento en una versión simple, sabiendo que se podría mejorar, haciendo que controle por ejemplo si el valor recibido es un array, etc):

```
function ordenDescendente($arrNumbers){
    rsort($arrNumbers);
    foreach ($arrNumbers as $k=>$v){
        print ($k+1)."°- ".$v.PHP_EOL;
    }    
}
```

Y para usarla con varios arrays:

```
$arrNumbers= array("7","3","1","5");
ordenDescendente($arrNumbers);
```

Obtienes:

```
1°- 7
2°- 5
3°- 3
4°- 1
```

Uso con otro array distinto:

```
$arrNumbers= array("9","3","7","1","5");
ordenDescendente($arrNumbers);
```

Obtienes:

```
1°- 9
2°- 7
3°- 5
4°- 3
5°- 1
```

Este es el tipo de funciones cadidatas para una **Clase utilitaria** en cualquier aplicación.

Espero te sirva.